# Is it possible to disable buttons in roMessageDialog?

Tags: brightscript

I want to show a `roMessageDialog` with some disabled buttons in a Roku app. Is that possible? I can't find anything in the documentation that says so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, no.

But i suppose you can fake it by changing the button text (e.g. putting in parenthesis or changing "Previous" to "No previous" :) ) and it's action (i.e. do nothing or beep disapprovingly).